# What is the difference between zero, nought and null?

Tags: single-word-requests

- Is null only a computer science word?
- Does nought refer to the digit only?

Comment: "Null" is a term of art in law, mathematics, and philosophy.

Comment: Null is not just a computer science word.  It's used in other context, for instance the stock phrase "null and void" - meaning that the referrent no longer has any effect.  Nor is NULL in CS necessarily zero: it's a pointer value that can't point to a valid address, so it could be implemented as e.g. all ones in binary - and that would be IMHO a lot more practical, since 0 is a valid address.

Comment: And *nought* has many uses besides just for referring to the digit "0" (which specific usage is moreover alien to American English). See [these in Shakespeare](http://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/search/search-results.php?link=con&works[]=*&keyword1=nought&sortby=WorkName&pleasewait=1&msg=sr), for instance.

Comment: "Null" is the German word for zero.. If your teacher, or his teacher, was Germain, you may use "null" for zero.  "Nought" used for zero is more common in the UK than in the US.

Comment: @gedgar also in Hungarian

Comment: The difference between the words depends largely in on the context you are using them.  In mathematics, null and zero refer to very specific things.  In language, each has a separate definition and connotation. Etc.

Comment: @GEdgar: But `null != 0` and `void` doesn't return a value at all!

Comment: _Nought_ is an old form of _nothing_ and now can also refer to the digit (as does _ought_, even though it's not negative). _Null_ and _zero_ refer to the digit.

Answer (score 2):

1. No.

> **null**
>
> 1. without consequence, value or significance
> 2. being or amounting to nothing

*Source: Dictionary.com*

2. Usually, yes. However, it can mean "nothing".

> **nought** (US English **naught**)
>
> 1. the number zero (0)
> 2. nothing

*Source: Cambridge Dictionaries Online*